# Handlebars get index two levels above

Tags: json, handlebars.js, parent

I'm trying to build a table with rowspan using handlebars and I'm trying to get the alternate row color to work in my favor.

Here's the template:

```
{{#each .}}
    {{#if_even @index}}
        <tr>
    {{else}}
        <tr class="oddrow">
    {{/if_even}}
    <td class="singlevaluecell" rowspan="{{#countmembers this.pools}}{{/countmembers}}">{{loadbalancer}}</td>
    {{#if this.pools.length}}
        {{#each this.pools}}
            <td class="poolcell" rowspan="{{this.members.length}}">{{this.name}}</td>
            {{#each members}}
                {{#if @first}}
                    <td class="membercell">{{this.name}} - {{this.enabled}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {{else}}
                    {{#if_even @../../index}}
                        <tr>
                    {{else}}
                        <tr class="oddrow">
                    {{/if_even}}
                    <td class="membercell">{{this.name}}  - {{this.enabled}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <td class="poolcell">N/A</td>
        <td class="membercell">N/A</td>
        </tr>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

And here's the data:

```
[{
    "pools": [{
        "name": "POOLNAME",
        "members": [{
            "name": "/Common/MEMBER01",
            "availability": "AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN"
        }, {
            "name": "/Common/MEMBER02",
            "availability": "AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN"
        }],
        "loadbalancer": "LBNAME"
    }],
    "loadbalancer": "LBNAME"
}]
```

Before I tried to do this using only one level (@../index), and that worked fine.

Should @../../index work? Am I doing some other mistake. I just can't figure it out.

Any suggestion/way to debug would be appreciated!

/Patrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not that `@../../index` was not working, but rather my table markup. :)

```
{{#each .}}
        {{#if_even @index}}
            <tr>
        {{else}}
            <tr class="oddrow">
        {{/if_even}}
        <td class="singlevaluecell" rowspan="{{#countmembers this.pools}}{{/countmembers}}">{{loadbalancer}}</td>
        {{#if this.pools.length}}
            {{#each this.pools}}
        {{#if @first}}
                  <td class="poolcell" rowspan="{{this.members.length}}">{{#trimpartition this.name type="hidepoolpartition"}}{{/trimpartition}}</td>
                {{else}}
          {{#if_even @../index}}
            <tr>
          {{else}}
            <tr class="oddrow">
          {{/if_even}}
            <td class="poolcell" rowspan="{{this.members.length}}">{{#trimpartition this.name type="hidepoolpartition"}}{{/trimpartition}}</td>
        {{/if}}
        {{#each members}}
                    {{#if @first}}
                        <td class="membercell">{{this.name}} - {{this.enabled}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {{else}}
                        {{#if_even @../../index}}
                            <tr>
                        {{else}}
                            <tr class="oddrow">
                        {{/if_even}}
                        <td class="membercell">{{this.name}}  - {{this.enabled}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {{/if}}
                {{/each}}
            {{/each}}
        {{else}}
            <td class="poolcell">N/A</td>
            <td class="membercell">N/A</td>
            </tr>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
```